# Operation precedence in coordinate transformation

Tags: matrices, affine-geometry

Consider two orthogonal, right-handed frames whose orientations and positions are as depicted in the below picture.
[image]

In order to bring the axes of frame {A} onto those of frame {B}, we can first rotate {A} about axis $Z_A$ $\alpha$ degrees counterclockwise and then translate an amount of s in the $X_A$ direction. We could do the opposite. The two operations do not yield the same result, what is more, first translating then rotating produces a false result.

Rotate and translate:

$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & s \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\
    \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & s \\
    \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
which is true; translate, then rotate:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\
    \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & s \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
   =\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & s\cdot\cos\alpha \\
    \sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & s\cdot\sin\alpha \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
which is false.

I know that the order of operations should be maintained when there are at least two rotations, but here there are just one translation and one rotation. My questions are,

Why don't one translation and one rotation commute?

Why did I get a false matrix when I first translated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha & 0 \\\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ is matrix of rotation *around coordinate origin*. In second case you want to rotate vectors around point $Z_B$, and matrix of that rotation is more complicated.

In general, when you want to rotate vectors about some point $A$, then you should translate $A$ to origin, do rotation of vector, and then translate rotated vector back to $A$.

Comment: When I first translate, the origin of frame A travels with the axes, so when I rotate afterwards isn't it still a rotation around the origin A?

Comment: Well, not really. You should be very careful about coordinates and basis. If your change of basis is represented as $f=eA$ then change of coordinates is represented as $v_e=Av_f$. So you first need to ask yourself do you want to see $A$ as coordinate transform or linear map. In your question you stated that you want to change frame (basis), but in your calculations you are taking $A$ as linear map. Take a look at [Active and passive transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation) it may clarify some things.

Comment: My mathematical background is not sufficient for now (I am an engineer), so shouId I stick to "deal with orientation and then with translation" for a while? :D

Comment: Try to calculate transformations for some concrete points ($(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$). You will see what is the problem exactly :)